# set vue data: object value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have Vue.ja app and I try to change a value inside an object. Basically when @change="onfilechangev" occurred I would like to update name: ' ' value 
Is there any way to do this or as it is an object I wont be able to update it?

**app.js**

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#regapp',
  data: {
       team:[
         {
           img: '',
           name: '',
          }
     ],
    },

methods: {
     onfilechangev(event) {
     let uploads = event.target.files[0]
     let pic = uploads.name;
     Vue.set(vm.team.name, 'pic', )
    },
```

Thanks for the answers. I have tried to do it but no luck. I have modified the codesandbox below to my situation. https://codesandbox.io/s/736nqq6070
little explain: I have dynamically added fields with optional profile image upload. So when I have added for example 3 team members then I would like to save them to the database with Laravel on the backend. if i select an image i push that file to the selectedFile array (it works), But as the profile pic only optional and not required somehow i need to know if teamemeber has image or not. That is why I try to set a hidden input field filename. so on the back end i can check selectedField array contains the filename if yes then i can save the image to the member.

Comment: team is an array, why are you treating it like an object? Should it be an array?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer but still nothing. There is no error simple just nothing happens .

Comment: i treat them as objects because they dynamically added fields so maybe there will be inside the team 1 img , name and 2nd img and name or maybe 3rd img, name.

Comment: You need to fix the `@change` binding. It is `$event`, not `event`. Use `@change="onfilechangev($event, index)"` and it should work.

Comment: @TommyF Thanks for your help, It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are only modifying *an existing property of an array member*, you don't even need to use `Vue.set`.

A simple `this.team[0].name = pic` will suffice, check this sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/l2ky6rkx0l

The JS limitations regarding reactivity only apply to *re-assigning an array element* or *adding a new root property*, neither of which is the case for you.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my original question and included a codesandbox to it.